# Check if a number is found x amount of times consecutively in a 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know if a number in a list is found j times consecutively ,this is my list :

```
list=[[1, 1, 1,1],
      [0, 0, 0,0],
      [2, 2, 2,2]
      [2, 2, 2,2]]
```

And this is what i wrote :

```
def alignment(list,n,j):
for y in range (n):
    for x in range (n-j):
        counter = 0
        for z in range(j):
            if list[y][x]== list[y][x+z]:
                counter+=1
            if counter == j :
                return True
```

But this function will check if any number is found consecutively,i want to add another parameter to this function so i can specify what number i want to look for in the list .
n means there are n rows and columns and j is how many times is how many times the number needs to be found .

Comment: *want to add another parameter to this function* - okay, what have you tried, and what doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you have a 2d list? What is the expected result? Do you want to check each sublist separately whether it contains the number x n-times in sequence?

Comment: @timgeb Yes that is exactly what i want to do.

Comment: also, at least n times, or exactly n times?

Comment: What is the meaning of parameters `n` and `j`?

Comment: @tobias_k n means the list is made of n number of lines and n number of columns ,and j is how many times the number needs to be found .

Comment: @timgeb Exactly n times .

Comment: So, when you say "exactly n times", or "exactly x times", you actually mean "exactly j times"? Also, Parameter n is not needed, just get the length from the list itself.

Comment: There are `n` rows and columns? Your question has 3 rows and 4 columns...

Comment: both of your observations are true ,i'll modify the question .

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

- the `n` parameter is not needed, you can get the size of the list by using `len(list)`
- you should not use `list` as a variable name, as it shadows the builtin `list` function
- with `for x in range (n-j)` you are assuming that each sublist has the same number of elements as the parent list
- your function also returns `True` if the number appears more than `j` times in a row
- you are doing lots of double work by using three loops instead of just two

You *can* fix this, and also add the parameter for the number to be repeated, as shown in the other answers. However, using just loops and conditions, the resulting code will be very unwieldy.

Instead, you can create a function as you describe using `any` and [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). `groupby` groups equal numbers, then you just have the check the `len` of those groups and see if `any` is long enough, and whether it's the correct number, for `any` of the sublists.

```
def alignment(lst, num, count):
    return any(any(n == num and len(list(g)) == count 
                   for n, g in itertools.groupby(l)) 
               for l in lst)
```

This will return `True` if `num` appears exactly `count` times consecutively in any of the sublists.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are unclear. However, this would be a slightly modified version of your code which would yield what I believe you're seeking.

**target** is the number for which you want to know if there are **j** consecutive entries.

```
def alignment(list,n,j,target):
    for y in range (n):
        for x in range (n-j):
            counter = 0
            if list[y][x] == target:
                for z in range(j):
                    if list[y][x]== list[y][x+z]:
                        counter+=1
                    if counter == j :
                        return True
```

Comment: @anantary this is exactly what i want but after testing it seems like it doesn't check the last number in each sub list .

Comment: @jumanji Glad it worked. I suggest you mark this as the accepted answer if you think my reply lead to the correct solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
def alignment(nums,j,target):
    for row in nums:  # get each row
        counter = 0 
        for i in row:  # get each number 
            if i != target:  # check if some other number was gotten
                if counter == j:
                    return True
                counter = 0  # reset counter
                continue
            counter += 1
        if counter == j:
            return True
    return False
```

No need for the `n` argument.